# How to overwrite at a specific position in a file in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, reader

My goal is to replace value at a specific position in a file in NodeJS without loading the entire content of file in the RAM (not `fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8")`). It should work with very large files (`> 2^28 - 16` bytes (V8 max allowed String length)).

This is my code :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = "./text.txt";
const cursor = 1;

(async () => {
        await new Promise((res, rej) => {
            const buffer = Buffer.from('ee');

            fs.open(path, 'w+', function (err, fd) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log('Cant open file');
                    rej()
                } else {
                    fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, cursor, function (err, writtenbytes) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Cant write to file');
                            rej()
                        } else {
                            console.log(writtenbytes +
                                ' characters added to file');

                            res()
                        }
                    })
                }

            })
        })
})()
```

This is the content of the `"./text.txt"` before I launch the program :

```
foo
```

This is the content of the `"./text.txt"` after I launch the program :

```
❓ee
```

and the charCode of ❓ equals 0.

This is the expected result :

```js
fee
```

What was wrong ? What should I fix ?

Comment: FYI, I added an alternative to my answer using `fs.promises`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using `w+` as the mode when opening the file. It should be `r+`:

```
fs.open(path, 'r+', function (err, fd) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags):

> `'w+'`: Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) **or truncated (if it exists)**.

*(my emphasis)*

So once it was truncated, writing to position 1 implicitly wrote `0` at position `0` (either that, or left indeterminate garbage there, I'm not sure it's specified which).

But with `r+`:

> `'r+'`: Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the file does not exist.

...you open the existing file without truncating, and then can write to the specific position.

---

For what it's worth, if you're using an `async` function, you might want to use the promises version of the `fs` API (`fs.promises`):

```
const fsp = require("fs").promises;

const path = "./text.txt";
const cursor = 1;

(async () => {
    const handle = await fsp.open(path, "r+");
    const buffer = Buffer.from('ee');
    console.log(buffer);
    try {
        const { bytesWritten } = await handle.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length, cursor);
        console.log(`${bytesWritten} characters added to file`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Cant write to file: ${err.message || String(err)}`);
    } finally {
        handle.close();
    }
})()
.catch(err => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err.message || String(err)}`);
});
```

Also note that you want to catch rejections of the promise your top-level `async` function may throw.